# Mysql query on linking table

Tags: mysql

I have a search form where people can select several services of companies, the tables are as follows:

**Business** business_id, business_name

**Business Data**

1, Prince & Son

2, Smith Ltd

3, Browns

**Services** service_id, service_name

**Service Data**

1, Shot Blasting

2, Painting

3 Steam Cleaning

**Business_service** business_id, service_id

1, 1

1, 2

2, 2

3 1

3 2

So if the user selected to search one item e.g Shot Blasting the sql will be :

```
Select * FROM business 
Inner Join business_service On business_service.business_id  = business.business_id  
Inner Join service On service.service_id  = business_service.service_id 
WHERE business_service.service_id = 1
```

Which works fine, but should the user search for a business that offers "Shot Blasting" AND "Painting" I would expect them to see business_id 1 and 3.  I know the following sql will not work but I thought I'd show  where i'd got to.

```
Select * FROM business 
Inner Join business_service On business_service.business_id  = business.business_id  
Inner Join service On service.service_id  = business_service.service_id 
WHERE business_service.service_id = 1 And business_service.service_id = 2
```

I know this is really simple but I just can't seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use OR instead of AND. Using AND mean return bussines_service where service id is 1 and 2 in the same time. Instead you want rows which have service id = 1 or service id = 2

Comment: Thanks, butI want to only show the business who offer both those services

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IN`

```
Select * FROM business 
Inner Join business_service On business_service.business_id  = business.business_id  
Inner Join service On service.service_id  = business_service.service_id 
WHERE service.service_id IN (1, 3)
```

Comment: this should be the vaues of (1,2) what you have put shouldn't have give any results at all but it did...it showed business_id 1 and 3 whp don't have a service_id value in the table

Answer (score 0):

you can use `in` instead of `where` and you should ideally have an `"OR"` condition for service id 1 or 2 . you query would be something like

```
 Select * FROM business 
Inner Join business_service On business_service.business_id  = business.business_id  
Inner Join service On service.service_id  = business_service.service_id 
WHERE business_service.service_id in (1,2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gave the folloing error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: I put an = instead of IN .. sorry about that